# How would I monitor the current buffered items/logs on my AmazonKinesis sink?

Tags: serilog, amazon-kinesis

Currently I have configured AmazonKinesis as sink on my serilog logger, after using the logger when I dispose the same I would want to know if there are any events/logs still remaining in the buffer which are not processed.

Below is the code snippet:

config.WriteTo.AmazonKinesis(options, kinesisClient);

I tried to check if there is any field/method on serilog/kinesis-sink that would provide the current state of buffer.

Comment: if you use a normal try/finally Log.CloseAndFlush, that should trigger the Sink to do its best to send all items. I'd have a look in that sink's impl (read the code) to see whether it in turn triggers a flush against the kafka client before returning or not. In general buffering sinks don't expose details about how much stuff is currently waiting in the buffer (in general a buffering sink is told a frequency at which it should flush it's buffers)

Comment: @RubenBartelink Thank you for responding. This makes sense to me, I confirmed this through debugging. Thank you!!